# Is it possible to use nuxt fetch() and set the values in head()?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The problem is that head() seems to be executed before async fetch(), which causes errors when trying to insert page's metadata and title. I KNOW asyncData exists, but the fact that it blocks page loading at a route transition level makes it provide such a HORRIBLE user experience (in a mobile device with bad connection, page transition can stay blocked for seconds) and reminds of old PHP rendered websites, not a modern SPA. Nuxt fetch() in the other hand, while still server side rendering the page, exposes `$fetchState.pending` and makes possible to exhibit an instant page transition showing the page skeleton, for example (consequently making the user experience better). The only problem i am having is this one with head() data. Is this problem solvable or just one unsolvable drawback of using fetch() instead of asyncData()?

Important Note: I am referring to Nuxt's new fetch method, not the legacy one.

example code that doesn't work:

```
data() {
  return {
    car: null,
  }
},
async fetch() {
  this.car = await this.$axios.$get('/cars/' + this.$route.params.id)
},

head() {
    return {
      title: this.car.name,
    }
  },
```

Comment: In your example you're using the legacy one. I'm not sure this is possible tbh, because `fetch()` can be used on pages and components. So, I'm not sure how defining a `head` for a `Button.vue` would work. It working for pages looks legit tho. Also, not sure if this may work maybe? https://github.com/ihavecoke/nuxt-seo-meta Never tried before.

Comment: You could always set it statically or have it maybe done afterwards somehow.

Comment: you're correct. The code snippet i provided was using the legacy one. I edited the question. I am trying to set the data at the page level. I will give a look at your link. thx

Answer (score 1):

My colleague did a talk a few weeks ago, speaking about SEO in general, here is related section: https://youtu.be/W9camkXNjkw?t=920

Looking at all my given answers regarding SEO and also Github issues, all examples are using `asyncData` or some static approach.
When you think about it, I'm not sure how you could generate something on SSR, while being totally dynamic + non-blocking.

Either you know it ahead of time and can generate the OG tags, or you don't if it's totally volatile.

Comment: But isn't the new fetch method compatible with SSR? As stated in nuxt docs: "Nuxt v2.12 introduces a new hook called fetch which you can use in any of your Vue components. Use fetch every time you need to get asynchronous data. fetch is called on server-side when rendering the route, and on client-side when navigating."

Comment: @Kos-Mos if you have it on the server, it will be during the initial loading. Subsequent navigations are done client-side. Simplest way would be to be sure of your `ssr` and `target` values in your `nuxt.config.js` files and debug it while having JS disabled: to see if it actually properly renders on the server or not.