# How to create 404 page on dynamic routes Nuxt js Fetch method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've dynamic route `http://localhost:3000/sections/slug-name`. I want to display or redirect to the 404 page if the URL is invalid. trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500137/nuxt-js-and-handle-api-404-response-for-dynamic-pages)  but with the fetch method.

I know we can do   `<p v-if="$fetchState.error">404 Invalid Section</p>` but is there any better way to show 404 page.

following is my code for your reference

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: {},
      loader: false,
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.posts.category_name ,

    }
  },
 

  methods: {
    getResults(page = 1) {
      if (this.$route.query.page != page) {
        this.$router.push({
          query: {
            page: page,
          },
        })
      }
    },

    loadPosts(page) {
      this.loader = true
      this.$axios
        .$get(`category/${this.$route.params.category}?page=${page}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.posts = response
          this.loader = false
        })
    },
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.loadPosts(to.query.page)
    },
  },
  async fetch() {
    let page = this.$route.query.page ? this.$route.query.page : 1
    this.posts = await this.$axios
      .$get(`category/${this.$route.params.category}?page=${page}`)
      .catch((e) => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'fallback-page' })
      })
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: as shown in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71980463/8816585), you can use this if you want the same behavior while using the `fetch()` hook

```js
this.$nuxt.context.error({
  status: 500,
  message: 'Something bad happened',
})
```

---

**Since you're using SSR, the part below is mostly wrong.**

If you don't have a route for a specific path, you could setup this

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    fallback: '404.html',
  },
}
```

and create a `/layouts/error.vue` file

```html
<template>
  <p>some error here {{ error }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['error'],
}
</script>
```

Thay way, if you reach upon `/hello-word` while it doesn't exist in your route, you will fallback to this one.

As explained [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts#error-page) and [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#fallback).

---

If you want a client side redirect after your fetch, you could always have a

```js
.catch((e) => {  this.$router.push({ name: 'fallback-page' })  })
```

after a `catch`.

Comment: hey, I cant use ```$router.push``` because I'm using the fetch method, it seems to be rendering component first that's why I'm getting ```Cannot read property 'category_name' of undefined
```

Comment: @KunalRajput this is some other issue. Your template is sync, if you have something like `object.category_name` but `object` is async, it will throw this error. Nothing related to a 404. Wrap your template into a `$fetchState.pending` while your API call is done, then display the rest of your template.

Comment: yeah in the head() I'm using ```title: this.post.category_name``` , how can I use ```fetchState.pending``` in the head method

Comment: @KunalRajput I've updated my initial answer with what you were looking for (regarding the `fetch()` hook). Meanwhile, regarding the SEO thing, this is a totally unrelated question. I've answered something [similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873451/8816585).

Comment: I'm not using SSG, I end up using asynData for this and it worked. Thanks for rescuing me again

Comment: can you update your old answer    ```this.$router.push({ name: 'fallback-page' })``` will work if I am not using head method,if I click on a link which does not exist it will redirect me to the 404 page ```<a href="/url-does-not-exist">Click here</a>```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, mind suggesting an edit? @KunalRajput

Comment: ```.catch((e) => {  this.$router.push({ name: 'fallback-page' })  })```       this code works like a charge if I like with the internal links in my nuxt application and page does not exist , So I was suggesting to put this catch code in the original answer

Answer (score 1):

you must use `error({ statusCode: 404})` in `catch` of fetch or asyncData method to redirect client to 404 page

Comment: client.js?06a0:56 Error in fetch(): ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: Put the codes you wrote to guide you exactly

Comment: I've updated the question with the code